# How to use Aurelia Getting Started tutorial with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

Aurelia has [a getting started guide](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/latest/doc/article/getting-started) which covers using TypeScript and VS2015.  I've downloaded the TypeScript Kit, and opened it as a website in VS2015.  I can view `index.html` in a browser.  However, when I edit `app.ts`, I don't see my changes when I reload `index.html`.  I use VS2015 Community Edition with update 2.  TypeScript is installed.

I'm missing something basic about how VS compiles TS into JS.

Any ideas?

[Edit]
The JS console contains debug statements about several Aurelia plugins being loaded and configured.  It then reports that Aurelia has started.  Lastly, it says that resources are imported for `app.html`.  I see no errors in the console.

Comment: What do you using for compiling your .ts files?

Comment: @kabaehr It's no need to explicitly compile TS, since the getting started `kit-typescript` use "in browser" TS compilation (by using [TS loader plugin](https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript) for SystemJS).

Comment: @royco Any errors reported in the console?

Comment: @qtuan no errors reported.  I updated my original question with more details.

Comment: @royco did you check if the updated file is really loaded? Sometimes I reload but the browser keeps serving the old file from its cache.

Comment: Ctrl-F5 in Chrome on Windows did not appear to clear the cache and reload.  However, I ticked "Disable cache" in Chrome's Dev Tools (under Network), and now I see my updates.  I wonder why Ctrl-F5 did not work.

Comment: @rocyo: you should than answer your question yourself (http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so others can better see, what was your concrete problem – and maybe it answers it for them, too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @qtuan suggested, the problem was that the page was being cached.  I initially thought this, and did Ctrl-F5 in Chrome on Windows to reload the page without using the cache.  For some reason, this did not behave as expected and I saw the original page.  When I ticked "Disable cache" in Chrome's Dev Toosl, under Network, then the page refreshed as expected.